# What are all the zone bosses?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I know some zones have "zone bosses" that provides quite an epic fight as well as a reward chest at the end of the event.

Sunless, Shatterer and Claw of Jormag are the three i know of. Does anyone have a more complete list of zones and their bosses?

Comment: The hardest boss is the one in Metrica Province: The Fire Elemental. I know Queensdale's Godlost Swamp has a Shadow Behemoth, Celadon Forest has a Giant Corrupted Jungle Worm, and The Norn area has a "Champion of Jormag".

Comment: Does the Fire Elemental have a reward yet?

Comment: @Gwen Fire Elemental drops a chest, just like all the other big bosses. The problem is, it's not very obvious, as there's no indication on the map or in the world that a chest has appeared.

Comment: Do update the official wiki if we get a list, as I'd be very interested in going to check them out, as I feel I've missed quite a few of these.

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of [Southsun Cove](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Southsun_Cove), every zone has at least one Meta Event chain, each of which culminates in a "boss fight". Since it's an event chain, you'd have to turn up at just the right time or participate in the whole series of events preceding the boss fight to actually face the boss and get the reward chest. (Speaking of the reward chest, note that there has been a change recently to give you a guaranteed Rare or better item per account per day from boss chests, or rather, from an additional chest - see the [official announcement](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/info/news/Upcoming-mega-boss-chest-change).)

For a complete list of meta events, have a look at [the wiki page](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Meta_event), which has been updated since DavidYell's answer was posted.

Quite often, people will announce meta events on map chat (e.g. "the maw is up!"). Alternatively, there is a very nice tool to let you find out when meta events are due at [Guild Wars Temple's Dragon Timer](http://guildwarstemple.com/dragontimer/events.php?serverKey=119&langKey=en) (you may wish to change the server of course).

Answer (score 0):

I'll get an answer started on this one and hopefully other users can edit it to add the ones I've missed out.
Most seem to be linked to [Meta Events](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Meta_event) which are zone wide and culminate in a boss battle, but some are much bigger than others.
Hopefully when we are done we can submit the list to the Wiki.

**Plains of Ashford**
[Siegemaster Lormar](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Kill_Siegemaster_Lormar) from [The Battle for Ascalon City](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/The_Battle_for_Ascalon_City) *(unconfirmed)*

**Queensdale**
[Shadow Behemoth](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Shadow_Behemoth) from [Secrets in the Swamp](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Secrets_in_the_Swamp)

**Caledon Forest**
Giant Corrupted Jungle Worm *(unconfirmed)*

**Metrica Province**
[Fire Elemental](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Fire_Elemental_%28boss%29) from [Thaumanova Reactor Fallout](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Thaumanova_Reactor_Fallout)

**Wayfarer Foothills**
[Champion Svanir Shaman Chief](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Champion_Svanir_Shaman_Chief) from [The Frozen Maw](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/The_Frozen_Maw)
[Champion Svanir Marauder](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Champion_Svanir_Marauder) from [Assault on Svanir's Dome](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Assault_on_Svanir%27s_Dome)

**Diessa Plateau**
[Hazarar Razenight](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Defeat_Hazarar_Razenight) from [Flame Legion Battles](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Flame_Legion_Battles)

**Kessex Hills**

**Brisban Wildlands**

**Snowden Drifts**

**Gendarran Fields**
[Ulgoth the Modniir](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Defeat_Ulgoth_the_Modniir_and_his_minions) from [Assault on Ascalon Settlement](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Assault_on_Ascalon_Settlement)

**Lornar's Pass**

**Fields of Ruin**

**Harathi Hinterlands**

**Blazeridge Steppes**

**Dredgehaunt Cliffs**

**Bloodtide Coast**

**Iron Marches**

**Timberline Falls**

**Sparkfly Fen**
[Tequatl the Sunless](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Tequatl_the_Sunless) from [Defeat Tequatl the Sunless](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Defeat_Tequatl_the_Sunless)

**Fireheart Rise**

**Mount Maelstrom**

**Straits of Devastation**

**Frostgorge Sound**
[Claw of Jormag](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Claw_of_Jormag) from [Breaking the Claw of Jormag](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Breaking_the_Claw_of_Jormag)

**Cursed Shore**

**Malchor's Leap**

**Southsun Cove**